# Arrange small images inside large UIImageView and zoom it in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a project that needs to arrange 81 small images(tiles) in a large `UIImageView` and zoom that `UIImageView`. I have to make three such UIImageViews
 (Example: with red tiles, blue tiles and yellow tiles [all 3 belongs to a single sheet]) and switch from one to another depending upon the zoom scale.

I have done it using the `CATiledLayer`.But I am not able to switch from one to another ,that means from red to yellow) depending upon the zoom scale. Also using CATiledLayer shows tiles loading in the screen which is not acceptable to my client.

**What I have done yet....**

I put the small images inside small UIImageViews. Then I arranged the UIImageViews inside a large UIImageView. I made three such large UIImageViews.I added the UIScrollView to my main view  by subclassing it and adding one of the UIImageView to it. Also I am able to switch from red to yellow and vice versa depending on zoom scale. But the problem is that when I make 3 large UIImageViews it shows memory warning continuously and when I press next button to load the next sheet (with 3 similar large UIImageViews), then application crashes.

Please somebody help me and resolve my issue because I am in a big trouble.

Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: Have a look at the WWDC 2010 video here http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/ , look for session 104 "Designing Apps with Scroll Views".